# How to create a build update in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, deployment, laravel-5.6

I want to know there is any way by which we can create a installer or some package for laravel application by which user can simple paste file and deployer will ask for db host and other setting and install application.

Also is there anyway by which we deploy a new build in current application and it will have all new updates which may contains updates in previous table. We want to keep data safe and release updates.

Comment: Did you try to use `mysqldump`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44608772/2594162)

### Install

To create installer for your application, you can [Laravel-Installer](https://packagist.org/packages/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer) package.

This package has following features:

- Check For Server Requirements.
- Check For Folders Permissions.
- Ability to set database information.

  - .env text editor
  - .env form wizard
- Migrate The Database.
- Seed The Tables.

### Update

Updating your database mean needs to migrate your database. You can run your migrate command through your application.

Run migration command from anywhere

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

With using route:

```
Route::get('/run-migrations', function () {
    return Artisan::call('migrate', ["--force"=> true ]);
});
```

Comment: This is for installing Laravel but my point is I want to update my application which is in laravel and I want to update features in my existing application.

Comment: Do you want to update application codes/ files? You can share your codes with `git` or you can ask them update your files in their project folder.